# Bootstrap tooltip alignment off

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

not too sure what could be wrong, the tooltip alignment is off for the horizontal form, however if I change the form-control's left and right's padding to 0, it works (align center), can anyone please help?[image]

code:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
  <input id="lastNameAdd" name="lastName" data-bind="value: lastName" title="" data-role="validate" data-content="Last name is required." class="form-control" required="" placeholder="last name" data-original-title="last name" aria-describedby="popover270602">
  <div class="popover auto fade top in" role="tooltip" id="popover270602" style="top: -74px; left: 400.688px; display: block;">
    <div class="arrow" style="left: -323.806%;"></div>
    <h3 class="popover-title">last name</h3>
    <div class="popover-content">Last name is required.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide your custom css or is this happening with the default bootstrap css?

Comment: I am using the default bootstrap css, I am curious how the "left" was calculated in arrow and popover-content? could this be a bug?




here it is how the pop-over content rendered in chrome, notice how wide the "left" is
element.style {
    top: 366.391px;
    left: 1746px;
    display: block;
}

Comment: Hmm thats weird. I have not seen that before. Since you are using just the default bootstrap I would try a new install.